# How to run GCC compiled output on NTFS drive?

Tags: linux, permissions, ntfs

Basically, I have three major partitions on my machine as I'm dual booting:

- Partition1: Windows-7
- Partition2: Linux-Mint
- Partition3: SHARED_NTFS_DRIVE

Well, I've reserved only a minimal chunk of my disk for OS partitions, as the bulk of my data that consist of movies, songs, source-code, etc. reside on the shared NTFS portion so that I can use it from both Linux and Windows.

Now, problem occurs when I want to compile and run my cpp source files (which are on NTFS shared drive) from Linux. I'm able to successfully compile my source file by invoking:

```
g++ temperature.cpp
```

But, when I want to run the output by running the `a.out` file, I get the below error:

```
./a.out
**bash: ./a.out: Permission denied**
```

`ls -l` shows `a.out`’s attributes (permissions/mode) as `rw-`. I tried doing `chmod a+x a.out`, but it doesn’t work; after doing another `ls -l`, the file attributes again show only rw.

However, when I copy the `a.out` to my ext4 Linux partition, it runs happily! What can I do to run it on my NTFS partition?

Comment: Have you tried `chmod 755`?

Comment: I tried doing "chmod a+x a.out" but it doesn't work. After doing "ls -l", the file attributes again show only rw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exec` option must be used to mount the NTFS partition, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306768/how-to-run-c-binaries-on-ntfs-in-ubuntu-10-10 for details.